# React Native Google Sign In

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I have implemented Joonhocho's `react-native-google-sign-in` module for getting the google sign in to work in my app.

here's the link to the module. 
https://github.com/joonhocho/react-native-google-sign-in

All the steps are done right, the only issue comes when I add three lines of code to **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question? It's hard to answer a problem with half an error message.

Comment: Please try this , it working for me and easy to integrate.
https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin